# How can I determine the type of a cref in an XML doc comment with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a doc comment like:

```
/// <summary>This is an xml doc comment <see cref="MyClass" /></summary>
```

How can I get Roslyn to parse this for me and give me the determined type of MyClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the `CrefSyntax` node that corresponds to the type name and then you can use `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo()` to get the `ISymbol` you want:

```
string code = @"namespace Foo
{
    /// <summary>This is an xml doc comment <see cref=""MyClass"" /></summary>
    class MyClass {}
}";

var tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(code);

CrefSyntax cref = tree.GetRoot()
    .DescendantNodes(descendIntoTrivia: true)
    .OfType<CrefSyntax>()
    .FirstOrDefault();

var compliation = CSharpCompilation.Create("foo").AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
var model = compliation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

ISymbol symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(cref).Symbol;
```